# CloudSQL with unix sockets not accessible in CloudRun instance that built through CloudBuild

Tags: mysql, docker, google-cloud-platform, unix-socket

I'm pushing a simple cloudbuild code for WordPress with --add-cloudsql-instances but unix sockets not showing up, just an empty folder.

Instance is MySQL 8,--add-cloudsql-instances creates /cloudsql

```
steps:
# Build the container image
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build', '-t', '${_REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_ARTIFACT_REPO}/${_RUN_SERVICE}:$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
# Push the container image to Container Registry
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "${_REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_ARTIFACT_REPO}/${_RUN_SERVICE}:$COMMIT_SHA"]
# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args:
  - 'run'
  - 'deploy'
  - '${_RUN_SERVICE}'
  - '--image'
  - '${_REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_ARTIFACT_REPO}/${_RUN_SERVICE}:$COMMIT_SHA'
  - '--region'
  - '${_REGION}'
  - '--platform'
  - 'managed'
  - '--port'
  - '80'
  - '--allow-unauthenticated'
  - '--cpu'
  - '${_CPU}'
  - '--memory'
  - '${_MEM}'
  - '--min-instances'
  - '${_MIN_INSTANCES}'
  - '--add-cloudsql-instances'
  - '${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_MYSQL_INSTANCE}'
  - '--set-env-vars'
  - 'WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=:/cloudsql'
  - '--set-env-vars'
  - 'WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${BRANCH_NAME}-${PROJECT_ID}'
  - '--set-env-vars'
  - 'WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${BRANCH_NAME}-${PROJECT_ID}'
  - '--set-env-vars'
  - 'WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${_DB_PASSWORD}'
  - '--set-env-vars'
  - 'CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME=${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_MYSQL_INSTANCE}'
  - '--set-env-vars'
  - 'INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_MYSQL_INSTANCE}'
# Direct traffic to latest version
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['run', 'services', 'update-traffic', '${_RUN_SERVICE}', '--to-latest', '--region', '${_REGION}', '--platform', 'managed', '--async']
images:
- '${_REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${_ARTIFACT_REPO}/${_RUN_SERVICE}:$COMMIT_SHA'
```

I'm using Alpine Linux 3.13 as base docker image

Here is the output from the folder, note that it's owned by root with r+x permissions while my nginx service is using php:nginx

```
php@localhost:/# ls -lsa cloudsql
0 dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Oct 3 06:36 cloudsql
php@localhost:/cloudsql# ls -lsa
total 0
0 dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Oct 3 06:38 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 0 Oct 3 06:31 ..
```

Not sure if the issue resides on cloudsql implementation, or if it's a permission issue.

This is the MySQL instance describe from gcloud:

```
backendType: SECOND_GEN
connectionName: kinetic-xxx-xxxxxx:europe-west4:xxxxx-xxxxx
createTime: '2021-09-26T12:38:23.727Z'
databaseVersion: MYSQL_8_0
etag: 095cf2aacb4f7ce950e20eb74e7963497f72eb29f56eb6fd1a397ff4d55f8bd9
gceZone: europe-west4-c
instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
ipAddresses:
- ipAddress: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  type: PRIMARY
kind: sql#instance
name: xxxxx-xxxxx
project: kinetic-xxxx-xxxxx
region: europe-west4
selfLink: https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/kinetic-xxx-xxxxxx/instances/xxxxx-xxxxx
serverCaCert:
  cert: |-
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  xxxxxxx
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  certSerialNumber: '0'
  commonName: C=US,O=Google\, Inc,CN=Google Cloud SQL Server CA,dnQualifier=afc48ad4-53c1-4400-a403-1558b8886e77
  createTime: '2021-09-26T12:39:42.220Z'
  expirationTime: '2031-09-24T12:40:42.220Z'
  instance: xxxxx-xxxxx
  kind: sql#sslCert
  sha1Fingerprint: xxx
serviceAccountEmailAddress: xxx-kq7b97@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
settings:
  activationPolicy: ALWAYS
  availabilityType: ZONAL
  backupConfiguration:
    backupRetentionSettings:
      retainedBackups: 7
      retentionUnit: COUNT
    binaryLogEnabled: true
    enabled: true
    kind: sql#backupConfiguration
    location: eu
    startTime: 00:00
    transactionLogRetentionDays: 7
  dataDiskSizeGb: '10'
  dataDiskType: PD_SSD
  ipConfiguration:
    ipv4Enabled: true
  kind: sql#settings
  locationPreference:
    kind: sql#locationPreference
    zone: europe-west4-c
  maintenanceWindow:
    day: 0
    hour: 0
    kind: sql#maintenanceWindow
  pricingPlan: PER_USE
  replicationType: SYNCHRONOUS
  settingsVersion: '10'
  storageAutoResize: true
  storageAutoResizeLimit: '10'
  tier: db-custom-1-3840
state: RUNNABLE
```

and this is the cloudbuild command:

```
gcloud beta builds triggers create cloud-source-repositories --name="stage" --repo="${REPO}" --branch-pattern="^stage$" --included-files="**" --ignored-files="**/*.md, install/vars, diagrams/**" --build-config="cloudbuild.yaml" --substitutions _ARTIFACT_REPO=${ARTIFACT_REPO}-stage,_REGION=${REGION},_RUN_SERVICE=${RUN_SERVICE}-stage,_MIN_INSTANCES=${STAGE_MIN_INSTANCES},_MEM=${STAGE_MEM},_CPU=${STAGE_CPU},_DB_PASSWORD=${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD},_MYSQL_INSTANCE=${MYSQL_INSTANCE}
```

Also updated the service account permission:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding kinetic-xx-xx \
>   --member="serviceAccount:xxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" \
>   --role="roles/cloudsql.client"
Updated IAM policy for project [kinetic-xxx-xxxx].
```

Also tried with Debian buster based image, same result, it's not OS related.

Comment: I've not used Cloud SQL with Cloud Run but am familiar with each of the services. Because Cloud Build is deploying, you'll need to grant the Cloud Build service account **all** the permissions necessary to both run the Cloud Run service and Cloud SQL permissions. Did you do that?

Comment: Just as a personal best practice, I think it's clearer and possibly less error-prone to use `- --key=value` in e.g. `args`. Your approach works as long as the order is unchanged but it's clearer to write e.g. `- --add-cloudsql-instances=${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_MYSQL_INSTANCE}`

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you shelling into the Cloud Run service to enumerate `/cloudsql`?

Comment: @DazWilkin phpbash.php ;)

Comment: @DazWilkin I've granted clodubuild service account both: Cloud Run Admin
Cloud SQL Client

Comment: Does the container run correctly including the socket get created correctly, if you deploy it without using Cloud Build? Trying to eliminate layers

Comment: @DazWilkin No change when deploying manually, no change even when switching to debian based image

Comment: @DazWilkin When testing with cloud_sql_proxy (what google recommends for testing It creates the socket inside /cloudsql